# Object doesn't support #inspect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

Getting an issue when running simple tasks in the ruby console.
If I run

```rb
user = User.find(10)
```

```sql
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "10"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

I get an 'Object doesn't support #inspect' error. My colleague has the exact same branch and has no issue. On other branches I don't have this issue either. There is definitely a result as running things like this are fine.

```rb
user.first_name
=> "Tom"
```

I have even deleted the branch, re-downloaded but still getting the same issue. Have removed the gemfile, bundled... tried everything I know. I even turned my laptop on and off.

Comment: May you have overwritten the User#initialize method? Would you like to add your User class code here?

Comment: @AgungPrasetyo - there's no initialize method as this is a rails project. On rails 6 if that's useful to know

Comment: kindly share your user model

Comment: I can't unfortunately. But I have even removed every custom method from inside User. 
It also happens to all my models. Not just User.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessarily a full answer to this question but we tried using the pry gem instead of IRB.

```
gem 'pry-rails'
```

Added this to our development group and now uses pry instead of irb. No issues.

Must be some sort of corruption on IRB. The version we were using was 1.3.5

Comment: I can confirm I am getting the same behaviour with the new default ruby debug gem in a Rails environment. pry-rails works fine.

Comment: Adding pry-rails fixed for me too. Must be a bug somewhere.

Comment: thanks! any idea why this happens in irb or how to fix it? because it looks like pry-rails is not being maintained anymore